# FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED crash

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run the following code in my app.
Unity's editor crashes when running it.
And on the iPhone the app freezes.
What am I doing wrong?
Firebase SDK 8.8.0.

> ERROR: FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: z:\build\work\006fabbe3c788f8159e582ced9f367dd4f3a\google3\third_party\firebase\ios\Releases\FirebaseFirestore\core\src\local\leveldb_transaction.cc(76) void _*cdecl firebase::firestore::local::LevelDbTransaction::Iterator::Seek(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > &): leveldb iterator reported an error: Corruption: corrupted compressed block contents (expected db_iter*->status().ok())

```
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
        DocumentReference docRef = db.Collection("posts").Document("656");
        Dictionary<string, object> uuu = new Dictionary<string, object>
                     {
                        { "text", "hello" }
                     };
        docRef.SetAsync(uuu);
    }
```

Comment: "Corruption: corrupted compressed block contents" - sounds like some local data got corrupted.  Reinstall?